# Erro na atribuição de um valor a uma variável

Tags: algoritmo, variáveis, tipagem, visualg

Estou fazendo alguns algoritmos no Visualg e me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> Erro na atribuição de valores à variável d: REAL para INTEIRO

Meu código é esse aqui:

```
Algoritmo "acertoMiseravi"
      d: inteiro Inicio
      escreval ("Digite dois números")
      leia (n1, n2)
      se n2 = 0 então
         escreval ("Impossivel Dividir")
      senão
         d <- (n1 / n2) //essa linha aqui tá dando erro
         escreva ("Divisão = ", d)
      fimse Fimalgoritmo
```

O que está errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É exatamente o que a mensagem de erro está dizendo. Você faz um divisão que gera um número com parte decimal, ou o chamado real, e está tentando guardar esse valor em uma variável que só cabe inteiros, portanto perderá a parte decimal, então dá erro. Pelo que entendo do código a solução é declarar `d` como `real` e não `inteiro`.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo seu algoritimo postado, ele não irá funcionar pois está faltando a declaração da variável n1 e n2, além de que não é permitido acento no `SENAO` e `ENTAO`.

Quanto ao motivo do erro citado, é por causa que a divisão irá retornar um número decimal, e portanto, você precisa declarar a variavel `d` do tipo REAL.

O algoritimo correto ficará desta maneira:

```
Algoritmo "acertoMiseravi"
var
n1, n2: inteiro
d: real

Inicio
      ESCREVAL ("Digite dois números")
      LEIA (n1, n2)
      SE n2 = 0 ENTAO
         ESCREVAL ("Impossivel Dividir")
      SENAO
         d <- (n1 / n2)
         ESCREVAL ("Divisão = " , d)
      fimse
fimalgoritmo
```

Uma dica: caso queira arredondar o número da divisão, coloque `2:2` ao lado da variável de divisão, ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
ESCREVAL ("Divisão = " , d:2:2)
```

Comment: Eu havia declarado as variáveis, mas havia tirado do tópico e não lembro o porquê, kk. O erro estava ocorrendo porque eu estava utilizando uma variável do tipo inteiro em uma divisão que resultaria um número real, mas muito obrigado pela dica e pela ajuda.

Comment: Se você quiser que o resultado da divisão seja um inteiro utilize o operador \ (divisão inteira) e não / (divisão real).